# perl hangs on exit (after closing a filehandle)

Tags: linux, perl, process, ipc, pipe

I've got a function that does (in short):

```
my $file = IO::File->new("| some_command >> /dev/null 2>&1") 
    or die "cannot open some_command for writing: $!\n";
...
undef $file;
```

Right now I'm not even writing anything to `$file`. Currently there are no other operations on `$file` at all. When I run the program, it doesn't exit properly. I see that handle is closed, but my program is still waiting for the process to close. Captured with `strace`:

```
close(6)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
wait4(16861, ^C <unfinished ...>
```

I don't see this problem if I open the same process for reading.

What do I have to do to make the program to exit?

Edit: Suggestions so far were to use the Expect library or to finish the input stream via ctrl+d. But I do not want to interact with the program in any way at this point. I want it to finish exactly *now* without any more IO going on. Is that possible?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Well - I just want the program to exit ;) - so far it just hangs on that wait4() call.

Comment: You may want to close the file, instead of undefining it. `$file->close`

Comment: undef closes the file according to perldoc. Also there's a close(6) in the strace output. (explicit `->close()` doesn't change anything either, tried that)

Comment: I understand you want the program to exit. What is the overall purpose of your program? The answer depends on that purpose and what `some_command` does.

Comment: @Sinan: You can treat it as an isolated case. It's some interactive program that I want to close with no further I/O going on. The command is not specified.

Comment: Okay, I guess if you really don't want help, you don't have to tell us what some_command is doing. Maybe you should investigate if it happens with other commands too. Good luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`undef $file` removes a reference count from the filehandle and makes it eligible for garbage collection. If `$file` is a handle to a regular file and there are no other references to the filehandle anywhere else, it should work as documented in `IO::File`. In this case `$file` is a handle to a shell command, and there may be some other internal references to the filehandle that keep it from getting destroyed. Using `$file->close` is safer and makes your intent much clearer.

---

To kill off the command when closing the filehandle doesn't work, you need the process ID. If you invoked the command like

```
my ($file,$pid);
$pid = open($file, "| some_command >> /dev/null 2>&1");
```

then you could

```
kill 'TERM',$pid;
```

at the end of your program. I don't know how to extract the process ID from the return value of `IO::File::new` though.

Answer (score 6):

If some_command is waiting for input, it will likely sit there forever doing just that, waiting for input.

From what the docs say, I don't think it makes any difference, but I always do $file->close() instead of/before undef'ing the handle.

EDIT: Send it Control D? 
Perhaps some_command is reading tty's instead of stdin, like passwd does. If you are in that realm, I'd suggest looking up Expect.

Control D simply duplicates the zero byte read that close should do anyway for a command line program.

Have you tried using $file->close() instead of the undef?

Comment: Yes, it does wait for input. How can I ensure that the program is closed if I only have that file handle available?

Comment: It does have a prompt. And I don't want/need the `expect` functionality. I'd like to simply force that process to exit. I don't want to send anything to the process, as I don't know what state is it in (and therefore what will CTRL+d do). I'm ok with killing the process and do not want it to do any more processing at that point.

Comment: Just to be more specific - It would be perfect if the process was killed. I do not want it act in any way when the pipe to my program is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Does some_command slurp all input and process it? Such as grep? 
Or does it prompt? Like, say... chfn? 
Does it return any useful information? Like an indication that it's finished?

If it's the latter, you might want to read up on [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) so you that you can interact with it.

Comment: It does have a prompt. And I don't want/need the `expect` functionality. I'd like to simply force that process to exit.

Answer (score 0):

This ugly, ugly hack will cause `some_command` to be parented to `init` instead of staying in your `perl`'s process tree.  Perl no longer has any process to wait for, and the pipe still works -- yay UNIX.

```
my $file = IO::File->new("| some_command >> /dev/null 2>&1 &")
```

Cons: The shell will succeed at `&` even if `some_command` fails, so you won't get any errors back.

```
    or die "cannot open some_command for writing: $!\n";  # now useless
```

If `some_command` exited as soon as it got an EOF on stdin (and never stops reading from stdin), though, I'd expect this wouldn't be necessary.

```
$ cat | some_command
^D
```

Does that hang, and can you fix that?